# Live USB flash drive with a persistent user home directory

Tags: ubuntu, liveusb

I want to be able to create a Live USB flash drive that I can run Ubuntu/Xubuntu on and be able to keep my configs intact. And maybe install some extra stuff.

Tried using the USB flash drive creator with the persistent storage. When booted into I would test by creating a random file in home Dir, reboot back into stick and see if there.

Do far it hasn’t worked.

Comment: From @PandaLion98: Try this. Maybe the USB live OS creator has some bugs. This explains how to do it manually:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence

Comment: Which release of ubuntu? unetbootin might work, but I want to test before I answer.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04. I tried unetbootin with the same result.  From the link provided, I saw mention to setting boot option to "persistent". I am going to try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the *persistent* boot option. With that you can edit the disk and things worked.

Steps:

- Create the USB using USB disk creator
- Boot into live USB
- as booting hit F6 for more options and type in "persistent" before the double dashes.